# How to find the residue via Laurent series when my contour encloses more than one singularity?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

What if I have a contour for a contour integral, and I want to use the Laurent series of the function I am integrating. However, my contour encloses more than one pole. Does this mean that every pole will have the same residue?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you mean.  To find the residue at a given pole you need to use the Laurent series based at that particular point, so there will be a different Laurent series to consider at each point.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up the residue theorem and Laurent series. The integral will be basically the sum of the residues at each of the poles. The residue at a given pole may be found from the corresponding Laurent series.

Comment: Oh, I thought that you could find the residue with the a(-1) coefficient of the Laurent series. Do I only use the coefficient, or also plug in the value of the point I want to take the residue at, and then use the resulting coefficient ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question makes sense.   Let's look at an example.   $f(z)=\dfrac 1{z^2+1}$ has singularities at $\pm i$.
Let's compute the integral $$\oint_\gamma f(z)\rm dz$$, for a regular closed loop $\gamma $ containing  $\pm i$.

We can use two Laurent series,  as a way to get the residues.

At $i$, we get $f(z)=\dfrac 1{(z+i)(z-i)}=\dfrac 1{2i}(\dfrac 1{z-i}-\dfrac 1{z+i})=\dfrac 1{2i}(\dfrac 1{z-i}-\dfrac 1{z-i+2i})=\dfrac 1{2i}(\dfrac 1{z-i}+\dfrac 1{2i}\dfrac 1{1--\dfrac{(z-i)}{2i}})=\dfrac 1{2i}(\dfrac 1{z-i}+\dfrac 1{2i}\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(\dfrac{z-i}{2i})^n)$, on $\lvert z-i\rvert \lt2i$.

Hence we can read off the residue and it's $\dfrac 1{2i}$.

The Laurent series at $-i$ is completely analogous. You get $\dfrac 1{2i}(-\dfrac1{2i}\sum_{n\ge0}(\dfrac {z+i}{2i})^n-\dfrac 1{z+i})$, so that the residue is $-\dfrac 1{2i}$.

Add the two residues to get the result (assuming the winding number is $1$).

The integral is zero.

Of course,  there's an easier way to get *these* residues.

Comment: Does this mean that if two singularities have the same Laurent series they will have the same residue ? And thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: Well yes, since it's the coefficient of the $-1$ term.   Sure.  They probably won't though,  because if the singularities are $z_1,z_2$, one will be in powers of $(z-z_1)$;  the other $(z-z_2)$.

Comment: And the Laurent series  converges within an annulus that avoids the other singularities. So generally you need to compute a different Laurent series at a different singularity.  The residues may turn out equal though.  And, depending upon the function,  there are different ways of getting the residues.

Comment: Besides,  you can't read the residue from the Laurent series until you do it at the singularity in question.